# latLng returns empty object- Google maps javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I use a google map with javaScript and my code is :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-12.043333,-77.028333);
        var myOptions = {
        zoom: 17,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
      };


      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
          myOptions);
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, "mousedown", function (e) {

                        //lat and lng is available in e object
                        var latLng = e.latLng;
                        console.log(latLng);
                    });
   }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>`
```

The result of e.latLng is an empty object.
I tried to click the event, but the result is empty.
What should I do or change?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Map), there is no 'mousedown' event on the Map class.  Maybe you want to use 'click' instead.

Comment: The object you are logging is a `google.maps.LatLng object`.  It has a `.lat()`, `.lng()`, and`to UrlValue()` methods, try using them... [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/sx6no99z/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine :

Click on map and your coordinates will come in `alert`

Please check [here](http://jsbin.com/gihipobafa/edit?html,output)

Comment: it still not working :( the result :Object { lat: _.F/this.lat(), lng: _.F/this.lng() } i'm working with localhost